# How do i get the url from a drupal webform url field in a webform handler

Tags: webforms, drupal-8

I created a webform handler and it's creating the node and passing all the content appropriately EXCEPT the url in one of the webform fields (the field 'Apply').

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Below is the code for the handler.

```
class HRJobWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    $pos_org = $values['position'] . "-" . $values['organization'];
    $node_args = [
      'type' => 'job_posting',
      'langcode' => 'en',
      'created' => time(),
      'changed' => time(),
      'uid' => 1,
      'title' => $pos_org,
      'field_salary_information' => $values['salary_information'],
      'field_apply' => [
            'uri' =>$values['apply']
            ],
      'field_more_information' => $values['more_information'],
      'field_position' => $values['position'],
      'field_organization' => $values['organization'],
      'field_area' => $values['area'],
      'field_job' => [
        'value' => $values['job_description'],
        'format' => 'full_html'
      ]
    ];

    $node = Node::create($node_args);
    $node->setPublished(false);
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Webform was posting the `Apply` field data as an array (it's a URL field). Code change to UPDATE: Webform post was passing the `Apply` link as an array. Code changed to:

```
'uri' =>$values['apply']['url']
```